# New GPU (1070), display is black, and windows wont load after driver update

Tags: windows-10, drivers, graphics-card, gpu

I have i7 6700 cpu, I just bought a new GPU (GTX 1070) and installed it.

Everything seem to be ok, the led on the GPU is fine but when I plug the monitor to it it wont display anything...

(I have Asus H170M-Plus motherboard if it helps)

What I tried based on the internet:

- Update BIOS
- Changed the setting on the motherboard to "Main Display - PCIE" (When I do that, the BIOS just ignore this and put "CPU" back in...)
- using DDU (Display Driver Uninstaller) to uninstall the previous GPU (the built-in one, didn't have a gpu before on this machine) driver.
- installed the current drivers from nvidia site.
- Checked if everything  is connected correctly
- Removing the GPU and putting it back (to confirm it is placed correctly)

When I install the Nvidia drivers btw, when it completes, I press restart and **windows wont load** at all, so I go to safe-mode and again using DDU to uninstall the driver..

So, what am I missing?

Thanks in advance.

(Windows 10)

By the way, I have 700W, so power is not the problem

Comment: What other versions of the driver have you tried?

Comment: I actually didn't, I'll try to search for other versions right now and update (Found one, trying 376.33, one before the latest)

Comment: @Ramhound No luck, after installing the driver and restarting Windows wont load :\

Comment: By the way, the display is keep going to the CPU, like the GPU is not there (I have one monitor connected to the GPU and one to the CPU)

Comment: Have you tried lowering the resolution on windows? I've seen issues before where the resolution will max out and the screen cannot accommodate for it

Comment: @RyanIG The problem is there is no display at all from the GPU.. I tried lowering the resolution but it doesn't work as well. I tried installing older version of the driver (36X) and still when the installation is done, windows wont load :\

Comment: @Zik332 How are you downgrading drivers if there's no display? do you have a second gpu installed or onboard graphics?

Comment: @RyanIG Yeah I have Intel graphics (HD 530) from the CPU. Basically I just use UUD to remove the nvidia drivers and install the version I downloaded from nvidia site.

Comment: To what port are you connecting the monitor ? Hdmi ? Dp ? Dvi ?

Comment: @YanivK HDMI to the CPU, DP to the GPU, I tried HDMI to the GPU as well but I get the same result.

Comment: Do you still have the old nvidia gtx ? If you do, try to install it and see what happens than. If all is ok, maybe your new gtx is faulty.

Comment: @YanivK I didn't have a GPU before that one, only the built-in of the CPU EDIT: You mean the driver? I tried installing 3, the latest, one prev to the latest, and 16X, all didn't work

Comment: Ooppss sorry missed the part where you said you didn't have a gpu before.

Comment: You say you do have signal when no drivers installed ?

Comment: @YanivK The lights on the GPU are on, the nvidia driver installation identify the GPU. I dont really know what you mean by signal from the gpu

Comment: By signal I mean that your monitor is able to display picture from the nvidia gpu only

Comment: BTY what monitor do you have ?

Comment: No, There is nothing from the gpu :\ even not the BIOS, it will only display from the CPU

Comment: I have 2 monitors, U2515H (Which I bought today btw :)) and S24B370

Comment: So you tried connecting only one cable from nvidia to the monitor and nothing ?

Comment: Yes, and I tried both HDMI and DP

Comment: Did you connect all the extra power cables that the new gpu needs ?

Comment: Yeah, I tried 2 different cables

Comment: @YanivK I just tried another one and I got signal!! but now how do I update the driver?

Comment: When I try to update it windows wont load :\

Comment: What exactly did you try ? Power cables ?

Comment: @YanivK Yes, I switched another cable and got signal

Comment: Tell me something, are the extra 2x6 pins that are needed for the new gpu are built in into your power supply? Or you are using an adapter cables ?

Comment: BTW just so you know, most GPU wont operate whiteout the extra juice (PCI-E 6pin power). So when you install drivers the card demands more juice and wont operate without it. So basically now that you have connected all the needed power cables, try to install the drivers and see what happens.

Comment: @YanivK It did the trick! Basically the cable from the power supply were split into 2 6 pins, I used the wrong 6 pins (I don't know how that would be wrong but it did) and now I installed the new drivers and everything is working correctly! :) Thanks again

Comment: You are welcome my friend, enjoy :)))